# I want to show array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a code :

```
$matematika = 60;
$ipa = 80;
$ips = 70;
$inggris = 90;

$dataNilai = array(
 'Matematika' => array($matematika),
 'IPA' => array($ipa),
 'IPS' => array($ips),
 'Inggris' => array($inggris)
);

foreach ($dataNilai as $key => $value) {
 echo $key.": ";
 foreach ($value as $key => $nilai) {
  echo $nilai."<br>";
 }
}
```

I want to sort and display the data array, as follows :

Inggris: 90 
IPA: 80 
IPS: 70 
Matematika: 60

Comment: Is there one element for `Matematika`, `IPA` etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_multisort

```html
$matematika = 60;
$ipa = 80;
$ips = 70;
$inggris = 90;

$dataNilai = array(
    'Matematika' => $matematika,
    'IPA' => $ipa,
    'IPS' => $ips,
    'Inggris' => $inggris
);

array_multisort($dataNilai, SORT_DESC );

foreach ($dataNilai as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.": " . $value . "</br>";
}
```

Comment: This would throw an error on `$value` variable since you need to cast the value from array form.

Comment: @Roshan sorry, can you explain?

Comment: @DamianDziaduch the `$value` variable holds data like `array(1) { [0]=> int(90) } array(1) { [0]=> int(80) }` so if you cast the `$value` as `echo $key.": " . $value . "</br>";` it will return an error that indicates `Array to string conversion`. Another is if you want to `echo` the `$value` it must be on the Traversable object form.

Answer (score 0):

try to use [array_multisort()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) to sort your desired output whether ASC or DESC order.

Add this code before your looping

```
array_multisort($dataNilai,SORT_DESC);
```

This function will automatically sort the data on array before casting/echoing it.

**OUTPUT:**

```
Inggris: 90
IPA: 80
IPS: 70
Matematika: 60
```

Hope this helps!